# How to rotate custom log file without reading it into String?

Tags: android

In my application I write custom log with this code:

```
public static void addLog(@NonNull String data) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getContext().openFileOutput("log.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I need to rotate it sometimes (just delete first 200 kb from start). I don't want to read it in String variable. How to implement it?

Comment: You need to use the scheduler for monitoring the log file.For each 10 min move and zip etc..

Comment: Why not use one of the existing logging frameworks?

Comment: @GautamJose, could you please to suggest some framework?

Comment: You can try log4j. API and configuration is simple .

sample

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10